# Haskell error on number operations

Tags: haskell

I've been searching for god knows how long, but couldn't get this piece of code to work:

```
solution n = 3/2*((n-n`mod`3)+3)
```

It compiles but when I call it, it throws two errors, the first one being

```
No instance for (Integral a0) arising from a use of `solution'
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve

```
solution 9 = 3/2* ((n-n`mod`3)+3) = 3/2 * ((9-0)+3) = 3/2 * (12) = 18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell won't let you add the `Fractional` (`3/2`) to the `Integral`

```
((n - n `mod` 3) + 3)
```

without explicitly telling it that you want to by adding a `fromIntegral` to the latter. So

```
solution n = 3/2 * fromIntegral ((n-n`mod`3)+3)
```

should work.

There's quite a good overview of all the numeric types in [Real World haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html#numerictypes.summary). I never remember the details though, and mostly just add in a `fromIntegral` whenever it's required.